# State of the art library for estimating differential entropy from real data

Tags: entropy

I am looking for a state of the art library for estimating differential entropy from finite samples. In an ideal world, it would have the following features:

- Work with real-valued multi-dimensional data
- Optimized for high performance (e.g. Implemented in C)
- Be aware of biases in sample entropy estimators and correct them (see, e.g. [Paninski2003](https://www.cns.nyu.edu/pub/lcv/paninski-infoEst-2003.pdf))
- Use something better than naive binning estimator (e.g. [Kraskov](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.69.066138) estimator)

What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: off-topic as there is the https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for these kind of questions (but personally I don't mind).

Secondly, you can't prove a negative but *if your data is continuous and multidimensional*, I would say that probably nothing ticks all of these boxes out-of-the-box.

I have implemented the Kraskov estimator and a bunch of related measures in python as at the time there wasn't anything else publicly available apart from a couple of dubious scripts written in MATLAB on the Mathworks exchange ([my project can be found here](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/entropy_estimators/)). Most of the heavy lifting is either pushed down to C (as I use `cKDTree` to find nearest neighbours) or to LAPACK/BLAS (i.e. Fortran), so I don't think that there is much to be gained by further optimization. At least for my data sets, the python "overhead" is small compared to everything else.
I don't do any bias correction in the published version of the repository. This is by design as I think that if your interactions between variables are small enough that you need to worry about biases then you **really** need to worry about it. All bias correction methods have a bunch of assumptions baked in and providing anything out of the box does more harm than good, IMO.

Then there is [NPEET](https://github.com/gregversteeg/NPEET), which is also in python, also build around the Kraskov estimator, and very, very similar to my stuff (so similar in fact that when I first read the source, I thought they had forked my repo until I saw that they first published their code a month before me).

Finally, there is [MINE](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.04062), an algorithm developed in Joshua Bengio's group. Their approach is conceptually very different from Kozachenko/Kraskov, and a very interesting read. They published their method last year but there are already a couple of implementations on github. I haven't had a chance to try it out myself, nor have I looked in detail at any of the implementations, so I don't have an informed opinion on it (other than that I am big fan of Joshua Bengio's work in general). The paper looks very promising but I haven't seen an independent evaluation so far (that doesn't mean there isn't one, though). However, they are training a neural network with gradient descent on mini-batches to estimate the mutual information, so I don't expect it to be fast. At all.

For discrete/binned data, there is [Ilya Nemenman's NSB estimator](https://nemenmanlab.org/~ilya/index.php/Entropy_Estimation), which ticks all boxes apart from your first one, which presumably is your crucial criterion.

Comment: 1) I was not aware of softwarerecs, I will attempt to use it in the future 2) Huge thanks for your code/NPEET, it will save me a lot of time 3) Read the Bengio paper, also big fan, but in this case I am somewhat cautious. The method effectively uses a neural network as a density estimator, which should still have the same regularizing challenges as, e.g. KDE. Namely, the best density estimator is a bunch of dirac delta functions, which is obviously wrong. 4) As you mentioned, continuous data is indeed crucial, so discrete methods are of limited interest.